# My data is stored as a matrix and as a list at the same time?

Tags: r, tabular

I am using the `tabular()` function to produce tables in r (`tables` library).

I want to compute CI's from the data in the output (let `mytable` be the output from `tabular()`).  Simple enough I thought, except when I go to call a value from the matrix, I get the error `Error in mytable[1, i] - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`.  I thought this was odd, as when I call up a particular cell of the matrix (where `as.matrix` returned true for `mytable`), for example `mytable[1, i]` for some i, I get an interger.  I then do the `as.list` for mytable and get true also, so I am not sure what this means.  I guess the `tabular()` function stores the results as a special kind of matrix.

I am only trying to pull out the mean,sdev, and n, which I am able to just by typing the cell location, for example `mytable[1, i]` would return an 86.  However, when I try to call up the value in `qt(.975,df=(mytable[1,i]-1))` for example, I get the error above. Not sure really how to approach this except to manually enter the values into another matrix (which I would like to avoid).  Or, if I can compute CI's directly in the `tabular()` function that would work also.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall quote for you the Value section of the documentation on the function `?tabular`:

> An object of S3 class "tabular". This is a matrix of mode list, whose
>   entries are computed summary values, with the following attributes:
>
> rowLabels - A matrix of labels for the rows. This will have the same
>   number of rows as the main matrix, but may have multiple columns for
>   different nested levels of labels. If a label covers multiple rows, it
>   is entered in the first row, and NA is used to fill following rows.
>
> colLabels - Like rowLabels, but labelling the columns.
>
> table - The original table expression being displayed. A list of the
>   original format specifications are attached as a "fmtlist" attribute.
>
> formats - A matrix of the same shape as the main result, containing NA
>   for default formatting, or an index into the format list.

As the documentation says, each element of the matrix is a list. If your `tabular` object is called `tab` type `tab[1,1]` and you should see a list containing one of your table values. If I wanted to modify that value, I would probably do something like:

```
tab[1,1]$term <- value
```

just like you would modify values in any other list.

Type `attributes(tab)` and you'll see the items listed above, containing a lot of the formatting information and row/col headers.

Comment: Thanks.  That `$term` was the trick, although I am not really understanding how a an object can be  a matrix of lists, however this is probably due to my limited understanding of data structures and r in general.